# Changing paths to images in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain

I recently moved a friends blog onto his new web hosts but unfortunately the images are not working.

This is due to the old host having the following path for images:

http://www.example.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/imagename.jpg

The new host uses a different layout and has this path for the file:

http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/imagename.jpg

'Blog' has been removed.

**Does anyone know the easiest way to fix this issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this tutorial on [Exporting and Importing Wordpress](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/exporting-and-importing-wordpress/) very helpful in such situations.

Answer (score 2):

Use this query on your database:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.old-domain.com/blog','http://www.new-domain.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

[Search RegEx](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/) is a good plugin to be able to search and replace with Grep through all posts and pages. Also look in template files for hardcoded links in the form of `<>php bloginfo(); ?>` for the unneeded /blog/ in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Search replace is a good plugin as well as Search RegEx. Especially if your data to replace is widespread throughout your site. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/